# API gateway POST passing fields and throwing error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway for a POST request which calls a lambda function.

When I test the Lambda function, it works
When I test the endpoint in the API Gateway, it works.

However, When I call the function via a CURL request or via a website, I get the following error:

```
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Unrecognized token \'eyJtZXNzYWdlIjoiSSBsaWtlIGdpcmxzIGJ1dCBoYXZlIGEgd2lmZSBzbyBuZWVkIHRvIGJlIGRpc2NyZWV0LiBwcy4gSSBoYXZlIGEgYmlnIGNvY2sgOnAifQ\': 
was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token \'null\', \'true\' or \'false\')\n at [Source: (byte[])\"eyJtZXNzYWdlIjoiSSBsaWtlIGdpcmxzIGJ1dCBoYXZlIGEgd2lmZSBzbyBuZWVkIHRvIGJlIGRpc2NyZWV0LiBwcy4gSSBoYXZlIGEgYmlnIGNvY2sgOnAifQ==\"; line: 1, column: 124]"}%
```

When receiving that error, the call never makes it to my lambda function. So something in the API Gateway is blocking my request.

My CURL request looks like

> curl -i --location --request POST 'https://example.com/staging/transform' 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"message":"test"}'

What could be the culprit here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `'Content-Type: application/json'` as header with `-H` option.

```
curl -i --location -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --request POST 'https://example.com/staging/transform'  --data-raw '{"message":"test"}'
```